# Installing dependencies with conan on github actions takes too long

Tags: cmake, github-actions, conan

I have built a Github workflow that installs Conan to manage a bunch of C++ dependencies along with CMake. It works great and I can test that:

1. my environment works
2. my library builds
3. tests pass

at every commit.

However, it is not very convenient for repeated pushes, as the `Conan install dependencies` step takes too long. Is there a way to:

1. Bypass the Conan installation and reuse previous workspace if dependencies are unchanged (that is, most of the time)
2. If not, what is the "standard" to have an equivalent system configuration in place on my system for tests (Does Conan has a Python virtual environment equivalent, or should I use a Docker, or ... ?)

My workflow is the following:

```yaml
name: CMake

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

env:
  # Customize the CMake build type here (Release, Debug, RelWithDebInfo, etc.)
  BUILD_TYPE: Release

jobs:
  build:
    # The CMake configure and build commands are platform agnostic and should work
    # equally well on Windows or Mac.
    # You can convert this to a matrix build if you need cross-platform coverage.
    # See: https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/actions/learn-github-actions/managing-complex-workflows#using-a-build-matrix
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Get GCC-10
      run:   |
             sudo apt update
             sudo apt install gcc-10 g++-10
      shell: bash

    - name: Install Doxygen
      run: sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends doxygen graphviz

    - name: Conan installation
      id: conan
      uses: turtlebrowser/get-conan@v1.0

    - name: Conan version
      run: echo "${{ steps.conan.outputs.version }}"

    - name: Create default Conan profile
      run: conan profile new default --detect

    - name: Conan configure remotes
      run:  |
            conan remote add bincrafters https://bincrafters.jfrog.io/artifactory/api/conan/public-conan
            conan config set general.revisions_enabled=1

    - name: Conan profile update
      run:  |
            conan profile update settings.compiler=gcc default
            conan profile update settings.compiler.version=10 default
            conan profile update settings.compiler.cppstd=20 default
            conan profile update env.CC=[/usr/bin/gcc-10] default
            conan profile update env.CXX=[/usr/bin/g++-10] default
            conan profile update conf.tools.cmake.cmaketoolchain:generator=Ninja default
            conan profile show default

    - name: Conan install dependencies
      run:  |
            conan install . \
            -s build_type=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}} \
            --install-folder=${{github.workspace}}/build \
            -pr default \
            -b=missing

    - name: CMake configuration
      # Configure CMake in a 'build' subdirectory. `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` is only required if you are using a single-configuration generator such as make.
      # See https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html?highlight=cmake_build_type
      run:  |
            cmake -B ${{github.workspace}}/build \
            -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=conan_toolchain.cmake \
            -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}
      shell: bash
      env:
       CC:   gcc-10
       CXX:  g++-10

    - name: Cmake build
      run: cmake --build ${{github.workspace}}/build --config ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}

    - name: Cmake test
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
      run: ctest -C ${{env.BUILD_TYPE}}

    - name: Doxygen documentation generation
      working-directory: ${{github.workspace}}/build
      run: make doc

    - name: Documentation moving generated files
      run: mv ${{github.workspace}}/build/doc/html ./doc/api

    - name: Documentation deploy to Github Pages
      uses: peaceiris/actions-gh-pages@v3
      with:
        github_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        publish_dir: ./doc/api
```

Comment: I suggest looking into GitHub Actions caching

Comment: Ok, I will look a the technicals, meanwhile if anybody has any idea how to accomplis that in this case please feel free to comment :)

Comment: Is the building from source for all dependencies the bottleneck? (it typically is). The recommended approach would be to cache the prebuilt binaries (``conan upload``) in a server, the ArtifactoryCE is completely free, or you can try if the limits of FreeTier are enough for your use case.

Comment: @drodri fantastic, I was lookin for that! Yes, the bottleneck is the `conan install dependencies` step. I was trying to set the cache, I will have a look at conan upload!